# How to plugin the SSL certificate into bitbucket-pipelines.yml file as the tests are over HTTPS?

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have got tests which need to run over HTTPS REST API webservices from bitbucket server CI pipeline, can anyone tell me the step-by-step instructions to plugin the .crt certificate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similal issue, we got that resolved after adding the following line to the bitbucket pipeline yml file

keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -noprompt -alias -ouralias -file OUR.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass ourpass

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my time. Much appreciated.